# Is there a difference when using the Jira Rest API manually vs. programmatically?

Tags: json, vba, excel, jira-rest-api

Newbie to Jira Rest APIs...I want to login to my Local Jira server with a VBA program.  I can log in and use the REST API manually with a URL & get the JSON response I'm looking for, but every time I try to use VBA (Excel) to do it I get the following error

> {"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified
>   issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}

I'm using basic authorization.  Is there something else I need to do?  (I'm using the code below that I was able copy from other posts).  Maybe Jira sees my code as a different user than my login?

```
Sub JiraRestGetCall()
   Call JiraRest
End Sub


Private Function UserPassBase64() As String
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim arrData() As Byte

    arrData = StrConv("MyUserName:MyPassword", vbFromUnicode)

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData

    UserPassBase64 = objNode.Text

End Function

Public Function JiraRest()
    Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With JiraService
        .Open "Get", "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/NP-1.json", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & UserPassBase64
        .Send ""
        If .Status = "401" Then
            MsgBox "Not authorized of invalid username/password"
        Else
            Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
            MyRequest.Open "Get", "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/NP-1.json"
            MyRequest.Send
            MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [VBA-Web](http://vba-tools.github.io/VBA-Web/) to connect to Jira. Your code looks pretty fine else. If your base encryption is working properly I don't see where the error could come from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use to request data from Jira. It could definitely be cleaned up/generalized (not to mention adding error handling), but it works fine for my purposes.

Credit for most of this code goes to Patrick Patrick's answer here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Excel-VBA-gt-JIRA-REST-API/qaq-p/513605

It works by:

1. `Posting` a new Jira session, including your login information, and extracting the session ID from the response.
2. `Getting` whatever data you want, including the session ID in the header
3. `Deleting` the session

If you're doing a lot of `Gets` at once, you could split this up into 3 separate functions, and only run steps 1 and 3 once.

```
Function getJiraJSON(restURL As String, requestString As String, jiraUsername As String, jiraPassword As String) As String
    Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim postResp As String
    Dim cookieVal As String

    With JiraAuth
        .Open "POST", restURL & "auth/1/session", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check"

        .send " {""username"" : """ & jiraUsername & """, ""password"" : """ & jiraPassword & """}"""
        postResp = .responseText
        cookieVal = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(postResp, 42, 32) & "; Path=/Jira"  'Extract the Session-ID
    End With

    With JiraService
        .Open "GET", restURL & requestString, False

        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", cookieVal

        .send
        getJiraJSON = .responseText
    End With

    With JiraAuth
        .Open "DELETE", restURL & "auth/1/session", False
        .send
    End With
End Function
```

In your case, you would call it with:

```
MsgBox getJiraJSON("http://localhost:8080/rest/", "api/2/issue/NP-1.json", "myUsername", "myPassword")
```